# If $f$ is increasing, $g(k)\in\mathbb N$ s.t. $\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{f(g(k+1))}{g(k)}<\infty$, show $\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{f(2^{k+1})}{2^k}<\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $f:\mathbb{N}\to(0,\infty)$ be increasing and suppose that a sequence $g:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ exists such that $$\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{f(g(k+1))}{g(k)}<\infty$$ Show that $$\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{f(2^{k+1})}{2^k}<\infty$$

Resources: Index mathematical problems 1980-1984. NAVW 703 by J.J.A.M.Brands.

How can I prove it?

I have tried this: Note that since that $$\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{f(g(k+1))}{g(k)}<\infty$$ and $g$ is sequence, so there exits $C\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $$|g|<\left|C\sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{f(g(k+1))}{g(k)}\right|$$ but $$ 
\left|C\sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{f(g(k+1))}{g(k)}\right|>  \left|\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{f(g(k+1))}{C+1}\right|=\infty \implies g \quad \text{is not bounded}$$

but I think this is a dead end.

Comment: To avoid downvotes, please show your attempts.

Comment: ok, thank so much.

Comment: I don't understand why they closed the question.

Comment: Most of the votes to close were probably cast before you had shown your attempts. This is unfortunate, but very common. I would vote to reopen, but I don’t have enough reputation. You may consider asking a new question, now that your post fits the maths stack exchange guidelines.

Comment: Thank you very much Joe, I will try to ask the question again.